# c# linq to sql join problem

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

i am trying to do

```
using (UserManagementDataContext context = new UserManagementDataContext())
            {
                var users = from u in context.Users
                            where u.UserEMailAdresses.EMailAddress == "email@example.com"
                            select u;
                return users.Count();
            }
```

however, when i get to:

```
using (UserManagementDataContext context = new UserManagementDataContext())
            {
                var users = from u in context.Users
                            where u.UserEMailAdresses.
```

i do not get offered the EMailAddress name, but rather some neutral default-looking list of options in intelisense.

what am i doing wrong?

table Users

```
ID  bigint
NameTitle   nvarchar(64)
NameFirst   nvarchar(64)
NameMiddle  nvarchar(64)
NameLast    nvarchar(64)
NameSuffix  nvarchar(64)
Status  bigint
IsActive    bit
```

table UserEMailAddresses

```
ID  bigint
UserID  bigint
EMailAddress    nvarchar(256)
IsPrimary   bit
IsActive    bit
```

obviously, 1 user can have many addresses and so `Users.ID` and `UserEMailAddresses.UserID` have a relationship between them: 1 to MANY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserEMailAdresses` is a collection of email addresses, so it doesn't make sense to call `EMailAddress` on it.

You have to check if there is an email address in the collection that matches the one you're looking for :

```
var users = from u in context.Users
            where u.UserEMailAdresses.Any(e => e.EMailAddress == "email@example.com")
            select u;
```

Comment: thnx will try it. it does make more sense :) than what i was trying. my first real usage of linq (outside of following tutorials).